# How to link colors between cells in Excel

Tags: excel

I'm looking to link the color of cells on an Employee Training Log.

[image: Employee Training Log]

I want to be able to color in a cell on my list of documents if someone has read that document, and it will match the color of all the cells that have the same text automatically. I'd like it to be dynamic, where if I add some documents to our HR system, it won't render the code useless and will be able to quickly link the new document in my document list to any requirements for the job title. I'd rather avoid VBA if possible but will use if I have to.

I have figured out [a way to link the color of one cell to other cells through VBA](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4071-excel-link-cell-color-to-another-cell.html), but it isn't very dynamic, since if I move any of the cells around, the code won't work the way I want it to. On top of that, if I copy pasted the code to link another separate set of cells, it wouldn't work with any of the cells, even the ones that worked before copy pasting the code. Even if it did work, I'd have to copy paste the code upwards of 100 times for the first sheet, and if any document were added, I'd have to enter the change in code in 50 different sheets (to keep every employee's training sheet updated)

If there's any confusion about what I'm looking for, please feel free to ask. I appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: Have you looked into Conditional Formatting?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad I wasn't sure if Conditional Formatting  would do what I was looking for. I thought that was when it would change color of a cell based on what you type in the cell. I'm looking for something that will change the color of a cell based on the color of another cell. If Conditional Formatting can do that, I'll definitely look into that.

Comment: Conditional formatting can't base itself on the colour of another cell. That said: "...it will match the color of all the cells that have the same text automatically." Can't you set up a condition based on that text? What you describe and what you show seem to be two different things. Can you show a small example of existing data and expected result?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad I changed the picture in the post to reflect what I want to do. I want to change the color of the document in the Forms section, and it change the color of that document in all Job Requirements. If I set up Conditional Formatting rules like that, then the cells would just automatically turn green as soon as I put the rule in. There's quite a few documents that people haven't read yet and probably won't read for a long time. I want to put in the rules now so I don't have to put in a Conditional Formatting rule every time someone reads a document, just change the cell color.